# Music playlist not playing in web app using just_audio package for flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

I'm trying to use just_audio to implement a simple loop of a few songs that play while you use the app.

Here's my current code

```
class MyGame extends StatefulWidget {
    const MyGame({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyGameState();
        }
    }
  

class MyGameState extends State<MyGame> {

    void initState() {
        super.initState();

                AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();
                player.play();
                player.setVolume(1);
            
            
                final playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(
                  useLazyPreparation: true,
                  shuffleOrder: DefaultShuffleOrder(),
                  children: [
                    AudioSource.asset('assets/music/digitalIgnition.mp3'),
                    AudioSource.asset('assets/music/spunky.mp3'),
                    AudioSource.asset('assets/music/jazzyNYC.mp3'),
                  ],
                );
            
                player.setAudioSource(
                  playlist, 
                  initialIndex: 0, 
                  initialPosition: Duration.zero);
                player.setLoopMode(LoopMode.all);
            

        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                    setState(() {
                        currentState = 0;
                        dynamicTextA1 = "start";
                        dynamicTextA2 = "da";
                        dynamicTextB1 = "adw";
                        dynamicTextB2 = "settings";
      });
        });
    }
```

My thinking here is that I've initialised the player, then created the playlist and set it as the current audio source, then finally started playback.

However this doesn't work, results in just silence despite throwing no errors.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to specify inside
`AudioSource.asset('assets/music/digitalIgnition.mp3'), AudioSource.asset('assets/music/spunky.mp3'), AudioSource.asset('assets/music/jazzyNYC.mp3'),` the assets folder name. If you go to the debug console, you will see the following :
[image]

as you can see in the first line `Flutter Web engine failed to fetch "assets/assets/music/digitalIgnition.mp3"`

Correct code:

```
> AudioSource.asset('music/digitalIgnition.mp3'),
> AudioSource.asset('music/spunky.mp3'),
> AudioSource.asset('music/jazzyNYC.mp3'),
```